# Pseudoclass for stickied element

Tags: html, css, sticky

Assume I have an element with `position: sticky`. According to specification, it's a combination of `position: relative` and `position: fixed`. So, how can I know, is element already fixed ("stickied") or not? Maybe there is any pseudoclasses or something?

Comment: No such *pseudo-class* exists. Are you aware that `position: sticky` is an *experimental API* and should not be used in production? (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky) It is not yet fully supported and integrated into all browsers. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Browser_compatibility for browser compatibility and support

Comment: What do you mean by how do you know?  By looking at the class?  By looking to see if it has position sticky?  What does a pseudo class have to do with it?  It is very unclear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: There's no DOM modification when the element stick to the top. So I think it will be very difficult to detect it. You may try something with window.scrollY value or getBoundingClientRect().top of the element.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError well, I know everything about `position: sticky` compability. Obviously, if I use it, I have no reason to worry about "compablility with old browsers". The worst thing that can appear in old browsers is element will have it's initial position. I'm satisfied with it, thanks.

Comment: Good - just thought I'd point that out anyway. Sometimes these things don't just go without saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getBoundingClientRect().top` property of the sticky element.
Let say you have a sticky div (id "sticky") in a scrollable wrapper div (id "wrapper") :

**CSS :**

```css
#wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
}
#sticky {
    position: sticky;
}
```

**JS :**

```js
var stickyDiv = document.getElementById('sticky');
var stickyValue = 0; // will stick on the top of the div
stickyDiv.style.top = stickyValue + 'px';

document.getElementById('wrapper').addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    var distance = stickyDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    if (distance <= (stickyValue + 1)) {
       console.log('sticked');
    }
    else {
        console.log('not sticked');
    }
});
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/9u4q8grq/2/**

Of course you can change the event listener target to "window" if you want to apply this on the entire document.
As said by @UncaughtTypeError be aware that it's an experimental feature, not supported by IE (but ok with Edge).

Comment: Seems like there is no way to solve it without scroll event for now. Thank you for answer!